# Why isn't the application launcher letting me resize it?

Tags: launcher, kde, resize

I have resized it before, but I added KCalc to favorites and want to make it bigger but it wont resize if I drag from the top right corner.

[image]

Comment: KDE Forum - Menu size. Resize or going to be Resizable?: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=128771 . You could resize with the 'Alt + Mouse right click'. The size will reset when the session ends.

Comment: Why would it reset? Is there a way to make it permanent?

Comment: Because the plasma doesn't save the menu size when the plasma session ends. You could edit the Layout.minimumWidth and Layout.minimumHeight :  KDE Forum - HOW can i save startmenu-size in plasma 5.6.5 kubuntu16.04 ? - https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=135874

Comment: Thanks this worked. I had to open the file with Kate as root.

Comment: @user26687 Can you write an answer based on your comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Look for the file "FullRepresentation.qml" (mine was in /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.kickoff/contents/ui/FullRepresentation.qml)
2. Open terminal `sudo kate`.
3. Drag and drop "FullRepresentation.qml" or open it from the menus.
4. Edit the `Layout.minimumWidth: units.gridUnit * XX` and the `Layout.minimumHeight: units.gridUnit * XX` values to whatever you like. Those are the width and height values of the Kickoff menu.
5. Save

I've set mine to W28 and H40.